# How to insert session stored multiple items into database all multiple values using session id in PHP?

Tags: php

My shopping cart items stored in session but I want store all items in database.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
     $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
    $item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_price = $_POST['item_price'];
    $item_qty = $_POST['item_qty'];
     $total = $_POST['total'];

 mysql_select_db('shoppingcartdemo',   mysql_connect('localhost','root',''))or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("insert into ordernew (id,item_id,item_name,item_price,item_qty,total,status,member_id) values('','$item_id','$item_name','$item_price','$item_qty','$total','Delivered','$member_id')") or die(mysql_query);

header('location:payment.php'); 


}
?>
```

Comment: i don't see any SESSION item**s**

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` , it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_* ` or PDO instead.

Comment: Have you tried anything with SESSION , because I am not getting any stuff.

Comment: `or die(mysql_query)` ?? that'll most likely cause an endless loop on erroring out

Comment: Run `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` as seperate lines of execution

Comment: Actually dont ! Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: `mysql_select_db('shoppingcartdemo',   mysql_connect('localhost','root','')` huh??

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I honestly don't know where you got this code from, or how it was (or who) put together, but it's failing here, big time.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips for you:

- DO NOT confuse `$_POST` with `$_SESSION`
- DO NOT use `mysql` use `mysqli` or for extra protection against sql injection, use `PDO`. Here a useful link to learn about it http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers
- If it is a shopping cart demo you are trying to code, do not use the `price` amount submitted in a form. Always validate it against a value stored on the database.

Good Luck and read as much as you can.